# Cannot access Samba shares from Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, samba

I have a Windows 10 PC that has a problem accessing a network share.

The firewall is disabled, network is local, I tried accessing by IP address or domain name. Same workgroup. What is even more weird, from a Ubuntu VM on the same PC **I AM** able to access the same share, so it's something in Windows settings and not a networking problem.

I've went through quite a few answers on Super User and the web, but so far nothing worked.

Comment: Do you get any decent error messages? Does the connection time-out or anything else? As it stands, it is impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Windows 10 introduced a new version of the smb protocol and is possible incompatible with Sambe at the moment

Comment: no meaningful messages :( and btw, I have another Win10 Pc on the same LAN and it accesses the share just fine

Comment: I have got the same problem. I can ping the device but cant access the Network Share drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try *[How to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows and Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2696547)*. Windows 10 tries to negotiate SMB3_11, which Samba does not yet support.

Another possibility UNC Hardening (enabled by default in Windows 10) - try access an SMB share by the servers's FQDN and check that same name is in the server's `smb.conf` file. DNS aliases don't work.

Comment: Can you add a little explanation of how to accomplish the second paragraph?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added a password for the user for samba?

Use command `smbpasswd -a username` to grant access.